# Android Maps apiv2 issues - Force "Disable HW Overlays"

Tags: android

I am having a terrible time implementing the Google Maps APIv2 in a dialog activity.  Please see these Google issues to get an idea of the problems I am recieving:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4902

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4865

Unfortunately I haven't really found a solution that works for me, except for one that I have not found mentioned anywhere else; disabling HW overlays through the Android developer options.  Obviously I can not recommend my users to enable this option, so I am trying to figure out if it is possible to explicitly disable HW overlays, just for my application or per activity.

Thanks.

Comment: With respect to hardware acceleration in general, you can control that at the application, activity, or widget level: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: I had seen that, but it only supports API level 11+.  This is only a problem when using the Google Support Library and Google Maps.  The Google support library is capable of supporting devices at API level 8+.  The only reason for doing all of this is because Google discontinued the API v1 for their maps and we don't have another option.

Comment: "I had seen that, but it only supports API level 11+" -- hardware acceleration wasn't used before API Level 11, except for OpenGL. Use the techniques outlined in my linked-to Web page to control the hardware acceleration on API Level 11+ devices. If you are experiencing your problems on devices older than API Level 11, then your problem is not related to hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to apply a transparent view over the top of the map fragment.  This causes Android to re-render the map properly.